# How to get nodes by custom field value using EntityFieldQuery?

Tags: 7, database

I am trying many options, e.g:

```
$entities = $nodeQuery->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article') 
    ->fieldCondition('field_archived','field_archived_value', '1', '=') 
    ->pager(10)
    ->execute();
```

`field_archived` is the machine name of my custom field added to `article`. `field_archived_value` is a column inside `field_data_field_archived` table.

In this case I am getting error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'field_archived_field_archived_value
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct code is the following one.

```
$entities = $nodeQuery->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article') 
  ->fieldCondition('field_archived','value', '1', '=') 
  ->pager(10)
  ->execute();
```

Instead of `'field_archived_value'` you need to use `'value'`.

Answer (score 0):

In entity query, you need to write the machine name of the field, not the table name.